# Duplicate entity object without its Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have to duplicate an entity but not its Id and then treat the new entity as a separate object.
The set accessor of my entities Id are not accessible.  So I can't modify the Id and set it to null, and right now I am only allowed to do AddOrUpdate (based on the Id) in the db.
I cannot do a simple Add.
I need to be able to duplicate or clone different entities, so maybe a generic function will help me to do that, but I am lost about where to start.
Any help pls.?

Comment: Do you have to duplicate any EntityType of your Context? Do you have a common BaseClass? Can you modify the ClassCode?

Comment: Is Id a primary key?  When using Primary Key you can only have one row in database for each ID.  You have to use Update if you are changing an existing Primary Key Value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to leverage Automapper to perform the shallow clone. Automapper can be configured to ignore specific properties such as the ID, or all properties with inaccessible setters:

So given an entity like:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public int SomeId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public SomeObject(int? id = null)
    {
        if (id.HasValue)
            SomeId = id.Value;
    }
}
```

you can configure a mapper like so:

```
        var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<SomeObject, SomeObject>().IgnoreAllPropertiesWithAnInaccessibleSetter();
        });
        IMapper mapper = new Mapper(mapperConfig);

        var test = new SomeObject(1) { Name = "Fred" }; // object we will clone.
        var test2 = new SomeObject(); // example of an existing "new" object to copy values into...
        mapper.Map(test, test2); // Copy values from first into 2nd..
        var test3 = mapper.Map<SomeObject>(test); // Example of letting automapper create a new clone.
```

In both cases the ID column was not copied over. You may want to use the "test2" example to utilize context.Entities.Create to create a new tracking proxy for the new entity, though EF works fine with newed up POCO instances of the entity provided it is added to the Entities DbSet.